# Android Studio: работа с 2-мя устройствами одновременно

Tags: android, android-studio

Делаю приложения для планшета, которые должны соединятся по блютузу. Из-за этого мне надо работать с 2-мя планшетами одновременно.

Но когда я подключаю 2 планшета к компу - Android Studio видит только 1. Отключаю 1 - видит другой. Планшеты одинаковые.

Как можно решить эту проблему?